# How to best render large web pages of mostly tabular content (~5 MB) locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An application generates html output containing tables. The html file generated is very large, ~7 MB and as such takes a long time to render/scroll even on the latest browsers. This html content is to be manually curated (linguistics related project).

To improve page load times, I thought of initially dividing the content into multiple pages, where the reviewer would click on a link to go to the next page. However, it brings an undesirable break in continuity - something like infinite scroll or lazy loading of these tables would be a better idea.

These html pages are to be viewed locally (not fetched from a web server). From what I've read about infinite scroll / lazy load, it seems to work within a web server. I would like to avoid that.

Basically, can I lazy load content within a single page using javascript, but no AJAX/php?

This html output will be viewed inside a VM, so it is important that I decrease the page load time, which is about 2-3 minutes now.

-- EDIT --

The application takes as input an English text file to be translated and generates html output with analysis of each sentence. One table for each sentence, variable columns (words), fixed rows (element properties). This data has to be viewed manually, to check if the application has analysed the text correctly.

This application is provided as part of a VM image, as such page loading/render times are important. I would like to avoid packing in a web server (xampp) as part of the VM. AJAX requires a web server to fetch content?

How would I go about displaying only part of this static, long web page initially, and load the rest of the content as and when the user scrolls?

Lazy loading divs via something like lazyloadany [ http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-lazyload-any ] seems to be a relevant answer as of now. So, I just wrap a few of my tables in  tags, and use this jquery plugin to display all such divs?

Comment: I would basically go with Pagination, with an option to download the entire table as an excel file if the user wants to see everything. Thats just my opinion though. If you haven't heard of datatables.net plugin, do check it out. Helps in organizing the table view.

Comment: You will need some sort of AJAX in the background if you wish to lazy load content.  Why are you keen to avoid this?

Comment: How is someone meant to use this page - what are they looking for/doing?  A page this size seems like there is something seriously wrong with your UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Navigate a large table with JavaScript paging

This is something I have used in the past to navigate a large table structure. It obviously wont get around the download time for a 7Mb file, but then neither would AJAX. However, what it does do — at least for modern browsers — is skip out on the rendering of many rows (which with table rendering is what takes a lot of the time). By having the rows `display: none` as default, the browser should just ignore them.

I then use a little bit of js to create a pager interface which will then only show a number of rows at a time. How user friendly this interface is, is entirely up to you; I've gone with a horizontal input scroller.. but it could be anything really (just not the original page's scroll bar, that is rather tricky to do without knowing the exact height of every row prior to rendering, and nigh impossible if the rows have differing heights).

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot of what the fiddle produces]

#### Fiddle

Obviously this is showing a cut down table, if you introduce a larger table, you will need to tweak the slider's step value to accommodate i.e. the larger the number of rows, the smaller the step value should be. When testing this code with a table of about 9000 rows I needed a step of about 0.002 to fit on a small page.

http://jsfiddle.net/qXzzV/1/

#### Code

Here is the basic JavaScript, it is designed to work with modern browsers, if you need backwards compatibility for anything archaic I suggest you update the code to use a library like jQuery — the work should be minimal.

```
(function(){
  /// store our references
  var table = document.getElementById('target'),
      wrapper = document.getElementById('target-wrapper'),
      rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
      scroller = document.getElementById('scroller'),
      shown = [];
  /// core function, updates which rows are visible at what scroller offset
  var reveal = function(){
    var i, tr,
        s = scroller.step,
        p = +scroller.value,
        c = Math.floor(rows.length * s),
        l = rows.length,
        o = Math.floor(p * (l - c)) + 1;
    while ( (tr = shown.pop()) ) { tr.style.display = 'none'; }
    for ( i=0; i<c; i++ ) {
      if ( (tr = rows[o+i]) ) {
        shown.push(tr);
        tr.style.display = 'table-row';
      }
    }
  };
  /// update when the scroller is changed
  scroller.addEventListener('input', reveal);
  scroller.focus();
  /// transfer right and left arrow keys to the scroller (optional)
  window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if ( document.activeElement !== scroller ) {
      switch ( e.keyCode ) {
        case 37:
          scroller.value = parseFloat(scroller.value) - parseFloat(scroller.step);
          reveal();
        break;
        case 39:
          scroller.value = parseFloat(scroller.value) + parseFloat(scroller.step);
          reveal();
        break;
      }
    }
  });
  /// set the ball rolling
  reveal();
})();
```

Here is the expected mark-up:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="target">
<!--  your contents here //-->
</table>
<input id="scroller" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
```

...and expected (generalised) CSS, you should make this specific to your case:

```
table { width: 800px; }
th { text-align: left; padding-bottom: 10px; }
tr { display: none; }
tr:first-child { display: table-row; }
#scroller { width: 800px; margin-top: 30px; }
```

#### Going further

Considering that there will be people manually curating the data you should improve this UI to support value filtering/searching and the like, that with this design, is quite easy to do. You just need to step in at the point of where the rows are selected and put your own filter/selection code in place, and update the `rows` variable as and when the user changes their filters. Bear in mind that `getElementsByTagName` will return a live node list, which will be faster than a static node list or an array of elements. When/if you implement filtering code you should try and keep to using [live node lists](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/) if possible.

> **Some further table optimisation tips:** By specifying every cell width and height you should dramatically speed up a table's rendering speed. Also I remember reading that specifying a table's borders to collapse, using [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) can help with render speed, although I have not tried this myself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, in my case the tables are relatively small, just that there are a large number of them. The data as such cannot be organized in a grid like fashion (i.e one large table).

Comment: The principal is still the same, you can just switch from `tr` level to `table` level instead. Basically any element set to `display: none` will not take up render time, until it is set to display. Without seeing your markup I can't comment, but the above could be modified to seek and display a table at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement some kind of lazy loading. You don't need to have PHP or any other server-side code for that, but that doesn't prevent you to use AJAX in any case for data retrieving.

My suggested approach would be to store your large data in a separate JSON file (you can call it something like *data.json*), and your page script will make an AJAX call pointing directly to this file. The whole content of your data would be then available for your script to dynamically create the HTML elements to display the data.

Another similar solution, which doesn't involve AJAX at all, would be to create a normal Javascript file, which does a simple `var data = { /* all your data here */ }`, and reference that file using a normal `script` tag. The result would be exactly the same as the previous approach, so that you have a large Javascript object that contains all the data that you can render a bit at the time.